# Slow clonig of ContextMenuStrip.Items

Tags: c#, performance, clone

I have two Classes, each with their own `ContextMenuStrip`.
As each Obejct can be accessed from the other I want to embed each `ToolStripMenuItem` of one object be availabe in a `DropDown` of the others `ContextMenuStrip`.

The Objects are of type `MAC` and `TCPIP`
This is snippet of the MACs `ContextMenuStrip`:

```
ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
foreach (TCPIP ip in AssignedTCPIPentries) {
    mi = new ToolStripMenuItem(ip.IP + " - " + ip.Hostname);
    for (int t = 0; t < ip.SingleItemContextMenue.Items.Count; t++) {
        mi.DropDown.Items.Add(ip.SingleItemContextMenue.Items[t]);
    }
    cms.Items.Add(mi);
}
```

My Problem Is that if I am working with the TCPIP onbject and am accessing the ContextMenuStrip it imidiatly opens. (as intended)

When I call the MACs `ContextMenuStrip` and want to embed each `ContextMenuStrip.Item` of each Assigned TCPIP object to a Submenu (as seen in the code above) It takes Ages (About 10 seconds per TCPIP object) to complete (each TCPIP obejct hast 21 ToolStripMenuItems). But why is it performing so bad, and how can I avoid that?

Snippet of the TCPIP.SingleItemContextMenue part:

```
public ContextMenuStrip SingleItemContextMenue {
            get {
                ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
                ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem();

                mi.Text = "IP Infos [" + IP + "]";
                mi.Click += new EventHandler(showDetailedInformation);
                mi.Image = Toolbox.Properties.Resources.Info_64;
                cms.Items.Add(mi);

                cms.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator()); // Horizontal line

                mi = new ToolStripMenuItem("Copy IP [" + IP + "]");
                mi.Image = Toolbox.Properties.Resources.Copy_64;
                mi.Click += new EventHandler((ss, e) => general.copyStringIntoClipboard(ss, e, IP));
                cms.Items.Add(mi);

              //And some more...
                return cms;
            }
        }
```

PS: `foreach` did not work wile Iterating through the the `ContextMenuStrip.Items` because of enumeration issues. But I also did not get the reason for that. But maybe it has something todo with my issue?

Comment: just use the same menu and change the texts on the menu showing event

Comment: @Slai I don't think I get what you mean? Please explain it to me in a little more detail. thx

Comment: there is no need to create all menus and submenus beforehand. They can be created dynamically when needed .. like on a subitem mouse hover event

Comment: @Slai Ok but the submenus are not created beforehand. Those are dynamic parts that get created when called as properties of the object can be changed during runtime, and thus Items wont get created at all in the ContextMenuStrip. (see the getter in the TCPIP code snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SingleItemContextMenue` getter is called on each use of `ip.SingleItemContextMenue`

```
ContextMenuStrip cms = new ContextMenuStrip();
foreach (TCPIP ip in AssignedTCPIPentries) {
    mi = new ToolStripMenuItem(ip.IP + " - " + ip.Hostname);
    var ipSingleItemContextMenueItems = ip.SingleItemContextMenue.Items;     // get items

    for (int t = 0; t < ipSingleItemContextMenueItems.Count; t++) {
        mi.DropDown.Items.Add(ipSingleItemContextMenueItems[t]);
    }
    cms.Items.Add(mi);
}
```